# Has 1 Samuel 2:35 been fulfilled?

Tags: 1-samuel

1 Samuel 2:35
I will raise up for myself a faithful priest, who will do according to what is in my heart and mind. I will firmly establish his priestly house, and they will minister before my anointed one always.

Was Samuel prophesying about Jesus? Would not this contradict God's promise to the House of Aaron?

Comment: Who is Jesus in this scenario to you? The raised priest or the anointed one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prophecy about the house of Eli is contained in 1 Sam 2:27-36 and contains the following predictions:

- V31 - Eli's house would be destroyed and have no descendants
- V32 - Eli's sons would not reach old age
- V33 - All Eli's descendants will die by the sword (ie, in battle)
- V34 - Hophni and Phinehas will die on the same day
- V35 - a faithful priest will take Eli's place
- V35 & V36 - that successor will be great (using typical Hebrew idiom)

This prophecy was confirmed to the boy Samuel in a special revelation in 1 Sam 3:1-18.
It was fulfilled within the next few chapters of 1 Samuel; specifically

- 1 Sam 4:11 - Hophni and Phinehas were killed in battle on the same day
- 1 Sam 4:17, 18 - Eli died the same day as well
- 1 Sam 7; - 20 years later, Samuel effectively becomes Judge and ruler of Israel and leads them to overthrow the Philistines - see V15-17.
- The final fulfillment occurred when Solomon removed Abiathar the High Priest (1 Kings 2:26, 35) who was the last priest in the line of Eli.  [Thereafter, the descendants of Eleazar held the High Priesthood.]

Thus, the prophecy in 1 Sam 2 about Eli's house was fulfilled precisely and completely.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to note that a priest must be a son of Aaron. The faithful priest in this passage is Zadok. This has been fulfilled and can be shown in the the book of Ezekiel. It contrasts between the priests who were not faithful and those who descended from Zadok. It says regarding Zadok, "וְהַכֹּהֲנִ֨ים הַלְוִיִּ֜ם בְּנֵ֣י צָד֗וֹק אֲשֶׁ֨ר שָׁמְר֜וּ אֶת־מִשְׁמֶ֤רֶת מִקְדָּשִׁי֙ בִּתְע֤וֹת בְּנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵל֙ מֵֽעָלַ֔י הֵ֛מָּה יִקְרְב֥וּ אֵלַ֖י לְשָֽׁרְתֵ֑נִי וְעָמְד֣וּ לְפָנַ֗י לְהַקְרִ֥יב לִי֙ חֵ֣לֶב וָדָ֔ם נְאֻ֖ם אֲדֹנָ֥י יְהוִֽה׃" "But the Levitical priests who descend from Zadok, who maintained the service of My temple when the people of Israel went astray from Me--they **alone** will approach Me to minister to Me. They shall stand before Me to sacrifice to Me fat and blood --declares The Master G-d" (Ezekiel 44:15).

As in the answer by Dottard, these prophecies were all related to the near future for that time, not some far off event. These prophecies need to be read in context to be understood. Zadok was a priest at the time of Solomon only two or three generations after Eli. Second of all, someone who is not a male line descendent from Aaron **cannot** be a priest.